# Reason ports are toggling between no-response and host unrechable for the SAME machine, why?

Tags: nmap

I'm trying to learn pentesting and one thing that triggers me for my workshop is :

I have an ip address where all reason's ports are `no-response`, the status for all ports are `filtered` but when I re-do the same command with nmap (tcp packet), I have few reason's ports that turns into `host-unreachable` but all ports stayed `filtered`, for the exact same machine !

My command :`nmap -Pn -n @ip_add`

If there is a firewall, it should give me the same answer (deterministic) but that's not the case, so I was wondering what can be the origin please ? Do you have any hints ?

Answer (score 1):

> If there is a firewall, it should give me the same answer (deterministic) but that's not the case

Firewalls may be stateful. For example, iptables may be configured to reject the request with `host-unreachable` by doing `-j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable` if rate limiting condition such as `-m recent --update --seconds 3600 --hitcount 5` is met.

In your case it is possible that the firewall is configured similarly to detect many port scanning requests and reject with ICMP port unreachable.

You can try to use a more cautious timing template, such as `nmap -T2` (`nmap -T polite`) and see if it avoids triggering the rate limit. See [nmap documentation](https://nmap.org/book/performance-timing-templates.html) for details.